# Subdomain not working on WHM Control Panel

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, whm

I created a subdomain on my WHM CP but not working, the folder was created correctly and the VirtualHost too but when I try to access nothing happend and even when I try to resolve the host using the command **nslookup** display this:

```
nslookup testing.xxx.com
Server:         208.109.xxx.x
Address:        208.109.xxx.x#53

** server can't find testing.xxx.com: NXDOMAIN
```

And if I execute the same command to my domain:

```
 nslookup xxx.com
Server:         208.109.xxx.x
Address:        208.109.xxx.x#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xxx.com
Address: xxx.169.xxx.209
```

So, anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!

Following these instructions, now my subdomain works fine.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/subdomains-not-working-228132.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, I will edit your answer with the commands from the forum.

Comment: One doubt. Is there DNS entry needed for a subdomain?